# How to increase the number of columns in output table to show more detail

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 column headings of account_id, game_date and queue_type. I have to show how many games an account has played per queue_type. Atm I am able to show the total number of games played per account for a set time period but how could I dig down into the total and instead show the columns for queue type instead of total?

```
SELECT account_id, COUNT(*) as GamesPlayed FROM Games
WHERE DATE (game_date) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY account_id
HAVING COUNT(account_id) > 2;
```

This gives me two columns, the account id and then the total games played beside it, however instead of the total I would like the type of game played across the top as a column heading. There are 4 game types in total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation. You can count different types and assign them the column names needed. (Change the queue_type values per your data)

```
SELECT account_id
,COUNT(case when queue_type = 'A' THEN 1 END) as A
,COUNT(case when queue_type = 'B' THEN 1 END) as B
,COUNT(case when queue_type = 'C' THEN 1 END) as C
,COUNT(case when queue_type = 'D' THEN 1 END) as D
FROM Games
WHERE game_date >= '2012-01-01' AND game_date <='2013-01-01'
GROUP BY account_id
```

or more simply

```
SELECT account_id
,SUM(queue_type = 'A') as A
,SUM(queue_type = 'B') as B
,SUM(queue_type = 'C') as C
,SUM(queue_type = 'D') as D
FROM Games
WHERE game_date >= '2012-01-01' AND game_date <='2013-01-01'
GROUP BY account_id
```

Comment: you can use shorthand `sum(queue_type = 'A')` also

Comment: What if one of the queue types has a ' in the middle of the name?

Comment: you can escape it with a single quote. for example if you have `x'y` you would use `x''y`.

Comment: Again, tyvm vkp :)